# Why does this C++ class instantiation work?

Tags: c++, oop, instantiation

My friend showed me this interesting way to instantiate a class object:

```
Class *instance(new Class(args)).
```

Mind you, this was quite some time ago, and my friend can't seem to remember, or even understand, why he did it this way, and is genuinely curious as to why this even works. It was when I was still picking up pointers, so I just did the rest of my instantiations like this. Instead of, you know

```
Class *instance = new Class(args).
```

It works, but why? I have tried to find an answer to this but I struggle to describe it in a way so that a search engine could assist me.

I include below an example of my class definitions at the time. Perhaps the explanation lies there.

```
class Spacebox : public Skybox
{
public:
Spacebox(
    glm::vec3 _initPos,
    glm::vec4 _initRotation,
    double _oScale) : Skybox(_initPos, _initRotation, _oScale)
{
    mesh = new Mesh("Skybox.obj");
    shader = new Shader("Skybox");
    std::vector<std::string> faces
    {
            "Skybox/MilkywaySkybox/MWpositiveX.jpg",
            "Skybox/MilkywaySkybox/MWnegativeX.jpg",
            "Skybox/MilkywaySkybox/MWpositiveY.jpg",
            "Skybox/MilkywaySkybox/MWnegativeY.jpg",
            "Skybox/MilkywaySkybox/MWpositiveZ.jpg",
            "Skybox/MilkywaySkybox/MWnegativeZ.jpg"
    };
    texture = new Texture(faces);
}
~Spacebox() {}
};
```

Comment: it's very basic info about C++ initialization. You could always do `T x = value;` or `T x(value);` with the same result in most cases. C++11 added `T x{value};` as well  .

Comment: See [the forms initialization may take](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization). This is just another way of initializing an object, not very different from the `=` form.

Comment: @NathanPierson Yeah, immediately I had the thought that the two were equivalent, it was the new term that threw me off. It's just pretty much the heap analog to what M.M wrote. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @NathanPierson I'm still a bit confused. It seems like the object is being created twice. So, that must mean that the instantiation is being dereferenced and entered as the initialization value for the instance, right?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything being created twice. A `Class` object is created once. And a `Class*` pointer is created once. Nothing's created twice.

Comment: Yes, I understand now. Thank you again. Would you submit an answer? I suppose I could just answer myself and reference you.